# gzip compressed data(string/text) not getting in response

Tags: compression, gzip

On top off below rest API applying (GZIPOutputStream)GZIP Compression Filter.

Problem: 
1. Not seeing `greetings` in response
2. in somecases returning partial response
   Eg., Actual response: "Here is the simple text"
        Output response: "here is the sim"

Working scenarios: 
1. Working if add more text to the body
2. working if the response is a JSON

```
@PostMapping(value="/getSomeText")
public RespoEntity getText() {
  return ResponseEntity.ok().body("greetings");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you provide as information I need to guess a lot.

Sounds bit like a flushing error.  Maybe the sender does not flush its output buffer so that only partial data is sent.  You should double check that what is supposed to be sent is really received on the other end.  Enter debug output (if you can) in the sender and the receiver.